# How to launch a skype bot from URL

Tags: botframework, skype, skypedeveloper

I have a Skype bot and want to provide a link in a webpage that can be used to open Skype into a chat/IM with the bot. This is easy enough with regular users using the format "skype:-username-?chat" but this doesn't seem to work for bots.

Comment: How doesn't it work? Chat session does not start?

Comment: It simply opens skype and doesn't open a chat window with the bot.

Comment: As far as I know, Skype can't tell between bots and real people. It may sound stupid but have you checked that bot's username is correct?

Comment: Yes, have checked the bots name. It has spaces and tried filling them with %20, +, and - but none of those helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. 
   skype:28:11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555?chat 
where 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555 is the appId of the bot.

Comment: Nice one! Why '28', I wonder. This looks like the kind of undocumented feature that will one day stop working with no warning though :)

Answer (score 0):

Access an url of this format

```
https://join.skype.com/bot/MICROSOFT_APP_ID
```

where `MICROSOFT_APP_ID` is app id of your bot